# How to determine the calendar from which an Outlook Appointment Reminder is from

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, reminder

I'm currently using Outlook 2010 and am owner, obviously, for my personal calendar but also have a couple public calendars associated with my account. All appointment reminders show up in the same dialog apparently with no indication from which calendar the reminder is coming. I need to see if their source calendar name can be discovered to distinguish whether appointment requires action or is simply informational. Example: Personal Calendar indicates meeting at 10 am while Maintenance Calendar indicates an procedure that needs to happen that day and so the follow up to that procedure is the true action. By revealing the source calendar the appointment description remains useful to all users but may be interpreted differently based on the source calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, figured it out.

- In the reminder popup, double click the appointment to open its
  window.
- Then, in the ribbon, click on "File".
- If it isn't already selected, click "Info".
- Near the "Move to Folder" button, the source calendar is listed next to
  "Current Folder".

[image: Info pane for the appointment]